How does loop quantum gravity handle spacetimes which aren't globally hyperbolic, like the Kerr metric?
Loop quantum gravity assumes spacetime is globally hyperbolic. However, the interior of a Kerr black hole isn't globally hyperbolic, containing closed timelike curves. So, how are Kerr black holes handled in LQG?
